# get passed parameter from one windows application form to another windows application form

Tags: c#

I have to send parameter from one windows application to another windows application. I went through internet and got some idea but all I got was to send from one application to another console application. 
I have tried this so far.

```
windows application 1: 

                string cPath = "projectpath";
                string Fromdate = FrmDatetxt.ToString() ;
                string Todate = ToDatetxt.ToString();
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(string.Concat(cPath, "\\", "anotherapplica.exe"));
                startInfo.Arguments = Fromdate + " " +Todate;
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

windows application 2:

```
    namespace HREmployeeReport
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

            }



            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] args = new string[5];
                    var agrumentOne = args[0];
                    var argumenttwo = args[1];
                }
             }
     }
  }
```

I have to get that passed argument to my application 2 form. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can create a property on the target Window, then set the value of this property from the first window.

Comment: kindly show some code example so I can better get it.

Comment: [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get your arguments on the `Main` method of your `Program.cs` class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string arg1 = args[0];
        string arg2 = args[1];
        ///And so on...
    }
}
```

'args' is a string array containig all parameters sent to your application